# how to configure apache to redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I need to redirect HTTPS connections to HTTP site. The problem is there is a SSL certificate on the server. It has problems and we applied to get a new one. But google already indexed our site with https prefix and all firefox users coming from google search result lands on SSL error page. Explorer, Chrome, Safari works fine but Firefox gives SSL error page.

[image]

I tried the code below in .htaccess file but since SSL connection already established code below does not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Is there a way to tell apache never establish secure connection with client and serve non-secure version of the site?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. The SSL connection is the first thing that happens BEFORE any content (including redirects) can happen. You need a new, valid, cert to resolve.