# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP on Apache

Tags: .htaccess, ssl-certificate, http, https, apache2

I have a main domain and a couple of secondary domains hosted by a commercial web hosting service using Apache servers. Each domain has its own `.htaccess` file. I have only one SSL certificate, which is all I need, for the main domain.

However, if I type in the URL box (or a search engine directs to) `HTTPS://secondarydomain.com`, I get the web page warning about an invalid security certificate. When I confirm the exception, the browser displays the maindomain that is bound to the certificate. I read the post: [SSL priority](https://serverfault.com/questions/723932/how-to-configure-apache-to-redirect-https-to-http).  Is there nothing at all that I can do in this scenario to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP for the secondary domains?

EDIT for clarification:  I want the server to apply SSL certificate only to the main domain.  The sub-domains are wholly unrelated domains.  It is only confusing to people visiting those sub-domains to see a SSL certificate with the name of an unrelated website.  That is why I was hoping there was something I could put in the .htaccess files of those subdomains to make the server bypass or ignore the SSL certificate of the main domain.

EDIT:  I also tried an unconditional redirect with these lines in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect / "http://m y d o m a i n .com/"
```

Comment: I have answered an exact duplicate here: [it is possible](https://serverfault.com/a/846833/274176). Please upvote that answer if it's suitable for your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache with mixed http only and http/s virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/846778/apache-with-mixed-http-only-and-http-s-virtualhost)

Comment: Huh?  A virtual host?

Comment: The question is actually of the same situation. The secondary domains are called `VirtualHost`s in Apache's configuration.

Comment: And I am able to configure Apache on a third-party web host how?

Comment: If you want https URLs to work you obviously need a valid certificate for the domain. And once you have a valid certificate for the domain, I don't see why you would want to redirect to http in the first place.

Comment: There's a few reasons.  I need it becaue I have an express server running at port 8443 and I need it to be accessed via https from the main apache server.  @kasperd

Answer (score 1):

We also encountered scenarios before where we had client applications that could not support `HTTPS` that we needed to redirect back to `HTTP`.  We used the Apache `redirect permanent` on the `virtualhost` for `HTTPS` to force redirection back to `HTTP` for a particular application.

You might be able to use the following reference which they say works with `htaccess`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Here's a snippet that might help you achieve what you want:

```
<If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTP'">
    Redirect / "http://secondarydomain.com/"
</If>
```

I haven't tried managing the redirection using `htaccess` since we use `virtualhosts` but this seems possible also with `htaccess`.

Comment: I tried just the Redirect, without even any <If condition, and all I got was server error.  I edited above to show the lines I tried.